# ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor() returns ERROR_INVALID_SID on Windows 2000 only

Tags: winapi, advapi32

I've run into a problem where our code calls ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, (strangely MSDN says it's only availble from Windows XP onward, but everything else I find says it was introduced in Windows 2000), returns ERROR_INVALID_SID

where #define ERROR_INVALID_SID                1337L

on Windows 2000 only.  We use the same SecurityDescriptorString no matter the OS , so I'm not sure why it works fine on XP, Windows 7, etc..  This one has me stumped.

Comment: The documentation says it doesn't work on Win2K, and you're finding it doesn't work on Win2K.  I don't mean to be rude, but what is your question?

Comment: Carey Gregory, I assumed it was a mistake on MSDN because the export exists in advapi32.dll on Win2K.  Is it common for MS to introduce an API in one OS, but not actually make it functional until a later OS?

Comment: When Microsoft drops support for a given Windows version, MSDN tends to also drop any mention of that version as the minimum supported version for APIs - a practice that a lot of people hate, since it makes it hard to know when a given API was really introduced.

Comment: It's not common for MS to introduce an API in one OS but then not make it functional until a later version, but I'm pretty sure they've done it a time or two.  I can't cite a specific example because I'm working purely from vague memory, but in the future I may cite ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor() as the example.